# How to throw an IllegalArgumentException properly?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function to get a summary out of a string argument

```
fun plusMinus(expression: String): Int {
    try {
        val numbers = expression.split(" ")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw e
    }
    var sum = 0
    val numbers = expression.split(" ")
    if (expression[0].isDigit()) {
        sum = numbers[0].toInt()
        for (i in 1 until numbers.size) {
            if (numbers[i] != "+" && numbers[i] != "-") {
                when (numbers[i - 1]) {
                    "+" -> sum += numbers[i].toInt()
                    "-" -> sum -= numbers[i].toInt()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

The problem there is the fact, that I don't understand how to throw an IllegalArgumentException right; there are the tests for this function:

```
assertEquals(4, plusMinus("2 + 2"))
assertEquals(6, plusMinus("2 + 31 - 40 + 13"))
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException::class.java) { plusMinus("+2") }
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException::class.java) { plusMinus("2+2") }
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException::class.java) { plusMinus("44 - - 12") }
```

So the exception should be thrown if there are: 1) no spaces between marks 2) no equal marks near to each other(like in the fifth test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two easy rules to follow:

1. even indexes in your split have to be numbers
2. uneven indexes in your split have to be `+` or `-`

All other cases can't be valid. Would this be enough?

```
numbers.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
    if (index % 2 == 0 && !value.matches(Regex("[0-9]+"))) throw IllegalArgumentException()
    if (index % 2 != 0 && !value.matches(Regex("[+-]+"))) throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

**Edit**: Has to be improved to cover for strings like `+ 1 - 1` :)

Comment: Would it not be more helpful to include a message in each exception, telling what the problem is?  Right now anyone calling your function has to guess what the problem was, and which element caused it.

Comment: Absolutely! I just wanted to create the first draft to point it in a working direction.